# What do I need to do to get the right input shape to a TimeDistributed layer?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have built a model consisting of a CNN feeding an LSTM. I've wrapped the CNN in a TimeDistributed wrapper. I've configured my training set (x values) to have a 5D shape (batch_size, num_steps, image_height, image_width, channels). When trying to train the model, I get the following error: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected time_distributed_input to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (4, 28, 28, 1).

I've tried a number of different model configurations, and have debugged through the code. I can see where the ValueError is being thrown, but I don't see any way to keep this from happening. Code details to follow.

my model-building code:

```
def build_cnn(input_shape=None):
    print('Building the CNN')
    model = tfkm.Sequential()
    if input_shape:
        model.add(tfkl.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
    else:
        model.add(tfkl.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(tfkl.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(1, 1)))
    model.add(tfkl.Conv2D(128, (4, 4), activation='relu'))
    model.add(tfkl.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
    model.add(tfkl.Conv2D(256, (4, 4), activation='relu'))
    model.add(tfkl.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

    # extract features and dropout
    model.add(tfkl.Flatten())
    return model


def build_lstm(units, return_sequences, dropout):
    print('Building the LSTM model')
    model = tfkm.Sequential()
    model.add(tfkl.LSTM(units, return_sequences=return_sequences, dropout=dropout))
    return model


def build_classification_layer(num_classes):
    print('Building the classification-layer model')
    model = tfkm.Sequential()
    # classifier with sigmoid activation for multilabel
    model.add(tfkl.Dense(num_classes, activation='sigmoid'))
    return model


cnn = build_cnn(input_shape=(28, 28, 1))
lstm = build_lstm(256, False, 0.5)
classification_layer = build_classification_layer(2)


combined_model = tfkm.Sequential()
#combined_model.add(tfkl.TimeDistributed(cnn, batch_input_shape=(20, 4, 28, 28, 1)))
#combined_model.add(tfkl.TimeDistributed(cnn, input_shape=(4, 28, 28, 1), batch_size=20))
combined_model.add(tfkl.TimeDistributed(cnn, input_shape=(4, 28, 28, 1)))
combined_model.add(lstm)
combined_model.add(classification_layer)
combined_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

.
.
.
data-set building:  creating 20 individual records, each containing a sequence of 4 28x28x1 images and the associated labels list.
.
.
.
print('train_input shape: {}  train_labels shape: {}'.format(np.array(train_input).shape, np.array(train_labels).shape))

print('Training the model')
combined_model.fit(train_input, train_labels, epochs=2)
```

output from the training attempt:

```
train_input shape: (20, 4, 28, 28, 1)  train_labels shape: (20,)
Training the model
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/scott/sandbox/CNN-LSTM-sandbox/build_and_train.py", line 184, in <module>
    combined_model.fit(train_input, train_labels, epochs=2)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/TF2_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 806, in fit
    shuffle=shuffle)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/TF2_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 2596, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "/anaconda3/envs/TF2_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 340, in standardize_input_data
    'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected time_distributed_input to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (4, 28, 28, 1)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Note that I get this same result regardless of which of the three `combined_model.add(tfkl.TimeDistributed(cnn...` versions I have in my code.

I'm not expecting a discrepancy between what the model thinks I'm providing and what I'm providing. I'm providing a 5D data set, and that's what it wants, but it claims that I'm only providing a 4D data set.

While debugging, I found the place where the ValueError is thrown. It is in `training_utils.py`, line 336 - `if len(data_shape) != len(shape):` (lines 303-350 shown for context):

```
lines 303-350 of training_utils.py:

  if len(data) != len(names):
    if data and hasattr(data[0], 'shape'):
      raise ValueError('Error when checking model ' + exception_prefix +
                       ': the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to '
                       'your model is not the size the model expected. '
                       'Expected to see ' + str(len(names)) + ' array(s), '
                       'but instead got the following list of ' +
                       str(len(data)) + ' arrays: ' + str(data)[:200] + '...')
    elif len(names) > 1:
      raise ValueError('Error when checking model ' + exception_prefix +
                       ': you are passing a list as input to your model, '
                       'but the model expects a list of ' + str(len(names)) +
                       ' Numpy arrays instead. The list you passed was: ' +
                       str(data)[:200])
    elif len(data) == 1 and not hasattr(data[0], 'shape'):
      raise TypeError('Error when checking model ' + exception_prefix +
                      ': data should be a Numpy array, or list/dict of '
                      'Numpy arrays. Found: ' + str(data)[:200] + '...')
    elif len(names) == 1:
      data = [np.asarray(data)]

  # Check shapes compatibility.
  if shapes:
    for i in range(len(names)):
      if shapes[i] is not None:
        if tensor_util.is_tensor(data[i]):
          tensorshape = data[i].get_shape()
          if not tensorshape:
            continue
          data_shape = tuple(tensorshape.as_list())
        else:
          data_shape = data[i].shape
        shape = shapes[i]
        if len(data_shape) != len(shape):
          raise ValueError('Error when checking ' + exception_prefix +
                           ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have ' +
                           str(len(shape)) + ' dimensions, but got array '
                           'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
        if not check_batch_axis:
          data_shape = data_shape[1:]
          shape = shape[1:]
        for dim, ref_dim in zip(data_shape, shape):
          if ref_dim != dim and ref_dim is not None and dim is not None:
            raise ValueError('Error when checking ' + exception_prefix +
                             ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have shape ' +
                             str(shape) + ' but got array with shape ' +
                             str(data_shape))
  return data
```

the state of things when the debugger hits line 336 is:

```
np.array(data).shape = <class 'tuple'>: (1, 4, 28, 28, 1)
data_shape = <class 'tuple'>: (4, 28, 28, 1)
name = <class 'list'>: ['time_distributed_input']
shapes = <class 'list'>: [(None, 4, 28, 28, 1)]
```

From this, one can see that the data shape getting to this point is correct, but the code pulls out the the first record in the batch and compares its shape to the shape the TimeDistributed layer is expecting. The problem is that the TimeDistributed layer is expecting a batch representation in the shape `(None, 4, 28, 28, 1)` but it's not there b/c the code only pulled the input record at that batch location `data_shape = data[i].shape`.

The way I see it, the batch dimension shouldn't be represented in the tuple that is used to establish expected shape of data to the InputLayer, the batch length comparison needs to ignore `None` in the shape tuples, or the comparison should be `if len(np.array(data).shape) != len(shape):`

Comment: Given that it's unlikely that any of the three conditions in the last paragraph will happen, how can I get the code to recognize that I am, actually, sending the correct shape?

Comment: made some progress on this. Added the designated line to the following block of code in `training_utils.py`, starting with line 296:

  ```if shapes is not None:
    data = np.expand_dims(data, 0)  # added by SQ
    data = [
        standardize_single_array(x, shape) for (x, shape) in zip(data, shapes)
    ]
  else:
    data = [standardize_single_array(x) for x in data]```
After adding this line, I can train the model.... I haven't verified that it actually works yet, but I'm no longer getting shape errors.